# Pandas Multi index dates summary

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to summarize a dataset so I can index on the 'Industry' and then the 'Reference_Date' with mean 'Average_Weekly_Earnings' the indexing works fine but I can't change the date to yearly, weekly, monthly, etc, and it's driving me insane.

I've tried both pivot and Groupby. When I run the following I get a multiindex as expected but how can I display the df and change the dates.

df1.set_index(['Industry', 'Reference_Date'], inplace=True)

[Generated Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LtGs.jpg)

From there I tried df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Reference_Date', freq='Y')).mean()
This does what I want but it drops the 'Industry' as the primary column, essentially I can't keep the multi-indexing. I'm a noob.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IgNp.jpg)

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: [**We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please post all text into the question with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Questions with images of text/code/errors are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure this & your future questions are suitable for this Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

```
df1.set_index(['Reference_Date'], inplace=True)
```

Then

```
df1.groupby('Industry') .resample('A').mean()
```